# Use old smartphone hardware as a torrent machine?

Tags: bittorrent, smartphone

Is it possible to use an ancient smartphone (2010 model) as a torrent seeder machine? Can somehow a bittorrent protocol be written for that system?

If so, will it run on these specs?

1] S-GOLD3H processor: http://www.mcuol.com/download/upfile/S-GOLD3H_MP-EH-pb.pdf

2] 30 MB internal storage, 8 GB microSD support

3] I don't know about the RAM - probably a few MBs (maybe less than 64 MB)

Comment: You don't mention what operating system it ran.

Comment: @Ramhound, it looks like android 1.x or 2.x, however I went into the phone settings and didn't find anything mentioning android. Online marketplace mentions the phone as having "proprietary OS".

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, unless,

- There is available/You are willing to write a compatible new firmware/OS for the phone that incorporates the torrent protocol; and then too only if,

  - The hardware on the phone allows new firmware to be written erasing the old one.
- The phone already has an OS that allows you to load and run arbitrary apps and there is a torrent app for the OS or you are willing to write one.

Comment: Ok, aside from the main topic, if the hardware does not allow new firmware to be written, then does it mean that the OS is loaded in some kind of ROM?.

Comment: Possibly. It could also be that the electronic connection that allows the firmware-write mode is not connected. So they program the chip at the factory and don't include the programming circuit on the distribution board. They could also lock it down so only firmware signed by them can be written (think Apple).